# DOJO timer pauses in Chrome

Tags: javascript, timer, dojo

I have a problem with timer, the problem is only in chrome and not in firefox

I Start the timer, when i change the tab in chrome the timer pauses till i switch back to the tab where i started the timer

**Can be tested as...**
Open the file(code attached below) in chrome, start the timer, after 5 secs open a new tab and be there for some time.... (say a min)
when u switch back to the tab where u started the timer.... timer is still in 5 secs and continues from there....

chrome pauses the timer when the tab is not active i guess....
how can this be fixed?

**code**

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("dojox.timing._base");
        var hours = 0;
        var mins = 0;
        var secs = 0;
        var mili = 1;
        var t;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showTimer() {
            t = new dojox.timing.Timer();
            t.setInterval(10);
            t.onTick = function() {
                if(mili == 100) {
                    mili = 0;
                    secs ++;
                }

                if(secs == 60) {
                    secs = 0;
                    mins ++;
                }

                if(mins == 60) {
                    mins = 0;
                    hours ++;
                }

                dojo.byId("my").innerHTML = "Time : " + hours + ":" + mins + ":" +secs + ":" + mili++;
            }
            t.start();
        }
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
</head>

<body class=" claro ">
    <p>
        Timer testing
    </p>

     <button id="buttonTwo" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
        Start Timer
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
           showTimer ();
        </script>
    </button>
    <button id="buttonThree" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
        Stop Timer
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
           t.stop();
        </script>
    </button>
    <div id="my">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like chrome just stops all (javascript) activity if the tab isn't active.
But the problem of time can be solved differently (I had the same problem before). When starting, you could have a var startTime = new Date().getTime();

The number of seconds passed since the start can then be calculated

```
var secondsPassed = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
```

gives you the seconds since the start of the document, from which you can determine the hours and minutes.
You do need to round things btw.

Answer (score 0):

generally speaking, timeouts aren't guaranteed to fire at the specified time.